# Select row once and perform calculation swift

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, closures

I have table view which displays a list of items and every time a row is selected, a checkmark is added and certain amount is added to `var total`.

If another row is selected it executes same behaviour as above and the previous amount for the deselected row is subtracted. Also the deselected row receives no checkmark.

The problem is that if a row is selected several times, it will keep adding the amount corresponding to the row selected.

What I want is to add the amount corresponding to the row only once regardless of how many times the row is selected.

```
class EighthViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

var total = 0

struct Item {
    var name:String // name of the row
    var selected:Bool // whether is selected or not
}

var frequency = [

    Item(name:"Every week",selected: false),
    Item(name:"Every 2 weeks",selected: false),
    Item(name:"Every 4 weeks",selected: false),
    Item(name:"Once",selected: false),
    Item(name:"End of tenancy cleaning", selected: false)
]

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return frequency.count
}
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

// configure the cell
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell     {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = frequency[indexPath.row].name
    return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = .Checkmark

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
    self.total += 30
        print(total)

        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        self.total += 30
        print(total)

         } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
           self.total += 30
           print(total)

    } else if indexPath.row == 3 {
        self.total += 40 
          print(total)

    } else if indexPath.row == 4 {
        self.total += 44 
           print(total)
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = .None

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        self.total -= 30
        print(total)

    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            self.total -= 30 // delete previous amount
            print(total)


         } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            self.total -= 30 // delete previous amount
            print(total)


    }  else if indexPath.row == 3 {
        self.total -= 40 // delete previous amount
         print(total)

    } else if indexPath.row == 4 {
        self.total -= 44 // delete previous amount
         print(total)
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created an struct with the a `bool` property `selected` so you can use it very easy to avoid the amount in the cell is added several times, and you don't need to use the `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` at all, to be notified every time a cell is tapped you need to use only `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method like in the following way:

But for a better use of your struct I recommend introduce the amount inside the type and the code would be more clean like in this way:

```
struct Item {
  var name:String // name of the row
  var selected:Bool // whether is selected or not
  var amount: Int // value of the item
}

var frequency = [

   Item(name:"Every week",selected: false, amount: 30),
   Item(name:"Every 2 weeks",selected: false, amount: 30),
   Item(name:"Every 4 weeks",selected: false, , amount: 30),
   Item(name:"Once",selected: false, amount: 40),
   Item(name:"End of tenancy cleaning", selected: false, amount: 44)
]
```

And we need to save the last cell tapped for every time we want to to update the new one so wee need to create a optional property like this one:

```
var indexPathForCellSelected: NSIndexPath?
```

And then the code should be like the following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if !frequency[indexPath.row].selected {

        // this avoid set initial value for the first time
        if let index = indexPathForCellSelected {
            // clear the previous cell
            frequency[index.row].selected = false
            tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(index)?.accessoryType = .None
            self.total -= frequency[index.row].amount
        }

        // mark the new one
        frequency[indexPath.row].selected = true
        tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = .Checkmark

        indexPathForCellSelected = indexPath
        self.total += frequency[indexPath.row].amount
    }
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. There are few issues with the code you have provided. In the first version every time a row is selected the amount corresponding to the row is added to `total`. The checkmark does not go away.  In the second version if several rows are selected, the amount is added to `total`, when they are deselected, the amount is subtracted, but the previously selected row does not lose its checkmark and the amount that was incremented once a new row is selected.

Comment: The behaviour I am looking for is : 1. select row -> add amount, add checkmark . 1.1 select row again -> nothing happens.             2.1. Select another row, set the checkmark for the previous row to .None, subtract from total the amount previously added, add checkmark to the newly selected row, add amount corresponding to the row selected. Thanks

Comment: @bogdanbarbulescu Uhmm see updated answer, your question was not very clear at the first time now it's clear. I hope this help you

Comment: I am trying the save the data to NSUserDefaults for the first version of the code you provided, but I can't get it to work. Here is the link of the question I posted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484660/error-when-trying-to-save-to-nsuserdefaults/38485168?noredirect=1#comment64373161_38485168  Thanks for your help.